# How to import Generic test data to SonarQube by using a REST API

Tags: sonarqube

How can I import generic test data into sonarqube. I can see in the doc that it can be done Report paths sonar.coverageReportPaths and sonar.testExecutionReportPaths, byt can I call this by using a REST API. If so how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Test data must be present and included at the time of analysis. Already-processed analyses *cannot* be updated.

As described in [the docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data), the property used to point to a report during analysis is `sonar.coverageReportPaths`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm new to SonarQube. Can you short describe or point to doc how I can get data for a program into SonarQube and the Test data by a REST API?

Comment: See my expansion @LarsKaareAndersen